# Typescript array of key value pairs declaration

Tags: arrays, typescript, key-value

Confused about the following declaration:

```
constructor(controls: {[key: string]: AbstractControl}, optionals?: {[key: string]: boolean}, validator?: ValidatorFn, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn)
```

What is the type of the controls (first parameter)?
Is it an object which is an array of key value pairs where key is string and value is AbstractControl? Thanks!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, like you guessed, it's a js object with key as string and `AbstractControl` as values.
For example:

```
{
    "control1": new Control(),
    "control2": new Control()
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can declare a variable to be of this type in two ways:

```
let controls: { [key: string]: AbstractControl };
```

or

```
interface ControlsMap {
    [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}

let controls: ControlsMap;
```

or even better:

```
interface ControlsMap<T extends AbstractControl> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

let controls1: ControlsMap<AbstractControl>;
let controls2: ControlsMap<MyControl>;
```

Comment: how would i declare a private variable of this type?

Comment: @mishap check my revised answer

Answer (score 2):

Aside of the above answer, you can also use the `Record<Keys,Type>` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) for this situation.

```ts
type ControlsMap = Record<string, AbstractControl>;

const mapping: ControlsMap = {
  keyA: new Control(),
  keyB: new Control(),
};
```

Or with generics:

```ts
type ControlsMap<T extends AbstractControl> = Record<string, T>;
```