# How to define a named array of objects in an interface with TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, node.js, typescript

How do I define the `restaurants` property in an interface with TypeScript?

```
let test = {
  user_id: 5,
  restaurants: [
    {
      restaurant_id: 5,
      restaurant_rank: 5
    },
    {
      restaurant_id: 6,
      restaurant_rank: 6
    }
  ],
  timestamp: 'test'
};
```

#### Note

I've looked at the following questions but none of them solved my problem:

[How can I define an interface for an array of objects with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25469244/)

[How can I define an array of objects in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35435042/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way I would write is like this:

```
interface IRestaurant {
    restaurant_id: number;
    restaurant_rank: number;
    restaurant_details?: any;
}

interface IThing {
    user_id: number;
    timestamp: string;
    restaurants: Array<IRestaurant>;
}

const test: IThing = {
    user_id: 5,
    restaurants: [
        {
            restaurant_id: 5,
            restaurant_rank: 5
        },
        {
            restaurant_id: 6,
            restaurant_rank: 6
        }
    ],
    timestamp: 'test'
};
```

There is a few other ways you can do the array:

```
interface IThing {
    user_id: number;
    timestamp: string;
    restaurants: IRestaurant[];
}

interface IThing {
    user_id: number;
    timestamp: string;
    restaurants: Array<{restaurant_id: number, restaurant_rank: number}>;
}
```

I noticed in your replied answer you do `restaurant_details: Object`. You should do `restaurant_details: any` because Object is more restrictive than any. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18961904/2592233

I also add a question mark after `restaurant_details` to tell the compiler this is optional since you didn't have in the first example.

Comment: So if the `restaurants` array could contain both `IRestaurant` and `IHotel` entries then only the first method would work, by having an `Array<IRestaurant | IHotel>` am I right?

Comment: I think that should work but I would use the new syntax and do `[IRestaurant | IHotel][]`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25469668/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36729729/) answers, I came up with the following:

```
 interface InterfaceName {
  user_id: number,
  restaurants: { [index: number]: { restaurant_details: Object, restaurant_rank: number } },
  timestamp: Date
}
```

However, I found out that it doesn't get detected as an array, so a simpler solution would be:

```
interface InterfaceName {
  user_id: number,
  restaurants: { restaurant_details: Object, restaurant_rank: number }[],
  timestamp: Date
}
```

Doing so will allow `InterfaceName.restaurants` to be correctly treated as `array` by the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: This worked well for me.